# E185: Cannot find color scheme for synload.vim (Line 19)

Tags: vim, colors, gvim

I've specified the location of `.vimrc` and `.vim`:

- `.vimrc` file saved at `~/.marslo/.vimrc`
- `.vim` folder saved at `~/.marslo/.vim`

After [set the `rumtimepath`](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc_PublicEnv#L36), plugins (installed by vundle) and colorscheme can be loaded successfully. However, there is a error shows while saving the file in every times:

```
Error detected while processing /root/.marslo/myprograms/vim74/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim:
line   19:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'marslo256'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The `colorscheme` named `marslo256.vim` which created by myself. Is there anything wrong with [`my colorscheme`](https://github.com/Marslo/marslo.vim/blob/master/colors/marslo256.vim) or [`my vimrc`](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc_PublicEnv).

If the `colorscheme` set as `desert`, then there nothing wrong. I pretty sure there something wrong with my color scheme.

---

By the way, this `colorscheme (marslo256)` has been used by me for long times, this error is the first time shows.

And my two colorschemes can be shown after press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in command line (I think that means nothing wrong with the `runtimepath` setting ):
[image: colorscheme]

The finial runtimepath (pretty much):

```
/root/.vim,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vundle,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/indentLine,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/gundo.vim,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/tagbar,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/authorinfo,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/EnhCommentify.vim,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-pathogen,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/MatchTag,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/supertab,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/auto-pairs,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/snipmate.vim,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/mru,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/Conque-Shell,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/taglist.vim,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/winmanager,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/accelerated-jk,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/MarsloFunc,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/groovy.vim--Ruley,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/groovy-vim-files,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/python_fold,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/pyflakes,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/python_match.vim,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/python-syntax,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-python-ftplugin,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-rails,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-textobj-rubyblock,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-textobj-user,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/ruby-matchit,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript-syntax,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-surround,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-repeat,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/rainbow,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/txt.vim,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-css3-syntax,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-coloresque,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/marslo.vim,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/MarsloVimOthers,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-markdown,/root/.marslo/.vim,/root/.marslo/myprograms/vim74/share/vim/vimfiles,/root/.marslo/myprograms/vim74/share/vim/vim74,/root/.marslo/myprograms/vim74/share/vim/vimfiles/after/.vim,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-markdown/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-css3-syntax/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-coloresque/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/snipmate.vim/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/indentLine/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/groovy-vim-files/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vundle/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/gundo.vim/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/tagbar/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/authorinfo/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/EnhCommentify.vim/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-pathogen/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/MatchTag/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/supertab/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/auto-pairs/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/mru/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/Conque-Shell/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/taglist.vim/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/winmanager/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/accelerated-jk/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/MarsloFunc/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/groovy.vim--Ruley/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/python_fold/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/pyflakes/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/python_match.vim/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/python-syntax/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-python-ftplugin/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-rails/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-textobj-rubyblock/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-textobj-user/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/ruby-matchit/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript-syntax/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-surround/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-repeat/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/rainbow/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/txt.vim/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/marslo.vim/after,/root/.marslo/.vim/bundle/MarsloVimOthers/after
```

Comment: What is your reason for not putting your stuff in its normal location?

Comment: The login username is a common account, I cannot configure a public account to my personal style...

Comment: Your sysadmin should be sacked. What is the final value of your runtimepath? It looks like a mess to me.

Comment: @romainl Actually, account is root....And the final runtimepath has been added in my question. I don't think there are something wrong with the runtimepath, because: 1. loading successfully; 2: Press ctrl+d in command also can load my colorscheme

Comment: OK, why do you put all your stuff in subdirectories of `/root/` instead of `/home/username/`? That's… beyond stupid.

Comment: @romainl Yes, that's a way, I just want to know **what's wrong with my color or my configuration**

Comment: And, I think you DON'T understand me completely. 1. I login server by account "root" (CANNOT using `/home/username` as my **home path**). 2. I don't want to change the default settings, I just using `vim -u ~/.marslo/.vimrc` to start vim by using my specified configuration.

Comment: 1. This should *never* happen and the person responsible for that mess should be hanged. 2. If you log in as `root` you can do anything, including creating a new user with his own `$HOME`. **What's wrong with your configuration is… everything.** You put your `.vim` directory in a non-standard place, you put Vim itself in a non-standard place, you introduce even more chaos by messing with `runtimepath`… the whole thing is a mess that can't and shouldn't be fixed. Install Vim system-wide, create a normal user for login, put your stuff where it belongs and don't mess with `runtimepath`.

Comment: Could you paste `/root/.marslo/myprograms/vim74/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim`?

Comment: @romainl Like I said before. I can **create** a new account, and I can set the configuration in the **new account home folder**. Does it matter??? The **root account still cannot be specified as my style**. Why are you so obsessed with the default vim configuration location?  Can the default location be changed? About the runtimepath analyse, I DON'T think you were read my question... AND, YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT I'M ASKING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigation, I want to say, this Error message has **NOTHING** related with my **specified localtion**!!!!

The real reason is, [there's a configure](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/e5ecf3afd4bca7d6e7fac4532aea71cae7f3f225/Configurations/vimrc_PublicEnv#L192) for **autoloading vimrc changes** while saving vimrc file. Because I found this error ONLY shows in saving `vimrc` file:

```
autocmd! bufwritepost $HOME/.marslo/.vimrc source %
```

And, I checked the **Line 19** in `syntax/synload.vim`:

```
17 " Set the default highlighting colors.  Use a color scheme if specified.
18 if exists("colors_name")
19   exe "colors " . colors_name
20 else
21   runtime! syntax/syncolor.vim
22 endif
```

That means, the error shows： **source vimrc** -> **exe colors marslo256**. I don't know the reason yet.

---

However, I found the **WORKAROUND** for prevent error shows: FORCE SILENT, the configure would looks like:

```
autocmd! bufwritepost $HOME/.marslo/.vimrc silent! source %
```

And everything's fine. Details can be found [at vim_dev google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/AnoL7ZC4fs8).

---

#### Root Cause

Finally, finally, the root cause shows up!!!!

The reason of this error shows, is **syntax is enabled before the sepcified location is added into vim runtimepath**.

The solution is

- **Move [line 19](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/832ab697418c294788376e4441cbc006d03566a1/Configurations/vimrc_PublicEnv#L19)
  (`syntax enable on`) to Line 97 (the end part of Vundle)**.
- [Line
  20](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/832ab697418c294788376e4441cbc006d03566a1/Configurations/vimrc_PublicEnv#L20)
  (`filetype plugin indent on`) can be removed (it's okay if it's keep),
  because this setting is duplicated with [Line
  96](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/832ab697418c294788376e4441cbc006d03566a1/Configurations/vimrc_PublicEnv#L96).

Details can be found at [vim_dev google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/AnoL7ZC4fs8/G_ruYCiep1YJ)

Answer (score -1):

```
put in marslo256.vim 
if exists("syntax_on")
      syntax reset
endif
let g:colors_name = "marslo256"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.  Do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.